# How to search for specific json value

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

To clear things up, I have an agenda where when I click a cell it opens up a modal window with certain gien information. At first I tried to use an iframe to pull in that information based off an attribute that the td element had. However, I am switching gears and I am now using data from a JSON array. When the data-ticker attribute is found in the array, I would like that information displayed on the modal window. However, I am confused as to how to use that data-ticker attribute as a search criteria.

```
 <script>
    const myRequest = new Request('_mmdata.json');

    fetch(myRequest)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => obj = data)
        .then(() => 
            let searchVal = document.querySelector('[data-ticker]');
            obj.values(data).forEach(e=>{
                if(e.page === searchVal){
                    console.log("This is the object: ");
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        )
        /* console.log(obj[0].name))*/

</script>
```

Here, I would like to use the same "data-ticker" attribute but I am not sure where to go from here.

```
<body>
<div class="modalWindow_container" id='modal1'>
    <div class="modalWindow">
        <div class="sidenav">
            <a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#a').show();"><i class="material-icons">event</i> Presentation</a> 
            <a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#b').show();"><i class="material-icons">person</i> Speakers</a>
            <a href="#link" onclick="$('iframe').hide();$('iframe#c').show();"><i class="material-icons">link</i> Links</a>
        </div>
     <br/>
        <div style='text-align:right'>
            <div class='button ok' onclick="hideModal()"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></div>
        </div>
        <iframe id="a" src="about.html"></iframe>
        <iframe id="b" src="about2.html" style="display:none"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Day 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Day 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="tzh">Time (ET)</div></th>
                    <th>Track I</th>
                    <th>Track II</th>
                    <th>Track III</th>
                    <th>Track IV</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>08:00</th>
                    <td data-ticker="syf" colspan="1" rowspan="2" class="pres">Presentation Title<span>8:00 - 9:00</span><span>Presenter</span></td>
                    <td data-ticker="about4" colspan="1" rowspan="2" class="pres">Presentation Title<span>8:00 - 9:00</span><span>Presenter</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
```

_mmdata.json

```
[
{
    "page": "syf",
    "name": "Synchrony Financial",
    "presenters": [
        {
            "company": "Synchrony Financial",
            "name": "Brian Doubles",
            "bio": "Brian Doubles is President of Synchrony, one of the nation’s premier consumer financial services companies.\r\nBrian is focused on Synchrony’s continued leadership in digital payments, accelerating growth across the company\r\nand driving the company’s strategic initiatives. Brian leads several key functions, including business strategy, venture\r\ninvestments and M&A, enterprise data analytics, customer experience, marketing (including new product introduction,\r\nproduct management and digital platforms) and the expansion of the company’s direct-to-consumer banking and\r\nproducts strategy.\r\nBrian was named President in May 2019, after serving as Executive Vice President and Chief Financial Officer for 10 years.\r\nAs CFO, he played a pivotal role in Synchrony’s initial public offering in 2014 and separation from GE in 2015. He was also\r\nresponsible for investor relations, financial planning and analysis, tax and treasury. Brian has a proven track record\r\noperating in various economic cycles and has earned a strong reputation for his deep domain expertise, strategic thinking,\r\nand financial and risk discipline. Prior to Synchrony’s founding, Brian served in various roles of increasing responsibility and\r\nmanagement at GE.\r\nBrian founded the Doubles Dive, an annual polar plunge event to raise money for various charitable organizations globally.\r\nHe earned a bachelor’s degree in engineering from Michigan State University. He is married with two children.",
            "title": "President",
            "pic": "/upload/event_68171/inv/3253491/Brian-dlpx (1).jpg"
        },
        {
            "company": "Synchrony Financial",
            "name": "Brian Wenzel",
            "bio": "Brian Wenzel is Executive Vice President and Chief Financial Officer of Synchrony, one of the nation’s premier consumer financial\r\nservices companies.\r\nAs CFO, Brian ensures the continued execution of Synchrony’s financial and growth objectives, bringing a deep understanding\r\nof Synchrony’s business, people and partners to help drive sustainable earnings and long-term strategic objectives. His\r\nresponsibilities include accounting and controllership, financial planning and analysis, tax, investor relations and treasury.\r\nPrior to his current role, Brian was Synchrony’s Deputy Chief Financial Officer, and earlier, the Chief Financial Officer of the Retail\r\nCard platform. As a member of the Retail Card leadership team, he helped develop and expand key partnerships, while taking\r\nresponsibility for strategic plans, quarterly operating results and financial management of new and\r\nexisting relationships.\r\nPrior to Synchrony’s founding, Brian held several roles in financial planning and analysis, treasury, pricing and controllership for\r\nvarious divisions at GE. Earlier, Brian worked for PricewaterhouseCoopers and held various roles in a start-up healthcare venture.\r\nBrian earned a bachelor’s degree in accounting from Marist College. He is married with three children.",
            "title": "CFO",
            "pic": "/upload/event_68171/inv/3253493/Wenzel_Portrait_4785_4887.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "profile": "Synchrony (NYSE: SYF) is a premier consumer financial services company. We deliver a wide range of specialized financing programs, as well as innovative consumer banking products, across key industries including digital, retail, home, auto, travel, health and pet. Synchrony enables our partners to grow sales and loyalty with consumers. We are one of the largest issuers of private label credit cards in the United States; we also offer co-branded products, installment loans and consumer financing products for small- and medium-sized businesses, as well as healthcare providers.\r\n\r\nSynchrony is changing what’s possible through our digital capabilities, deep industry expertise, actionable data insights, frictionless customer experience and customized financing solutions.\r\n\r\nFor more information, visit www.synchrony.com and Twitter: @Synchrony.",
    "logo": "/upload/event_68171/inv/3208967/syflogo.jpg"
},
{
    "page": "axp",
    "name": "American Express Company",
    "presenters": [
        {
            "company": "American Express Company",
            "name": "Jeff Campbell",
            "bio": "Jeff Campbell joined American Express Company in July 2013 as Chief Financial Officer, overseeing the company's financial operations worldwide as well as Corporate Development.  \r\n\r\nAs a member of the American Express Executive Committee and an officer of the company, Jeff plays an important role in developing the strategic direction for American Express and represents the company to the financial community.  In August 2019, he assumed additional responsibility as the CFO and as an officer of American Express National Bank.  \r\n\r\nBefore joining American Express, Jeff was CFO of the McKesson Corporation, the largest healthcare services company in the United States. He played an essential role as McKesson grew significantly and expanded its leadership in healthcare distribution and technology.\r\n \r\nPrior to his time at McKesson, Jeff spent 13 years at AMR Corp and its principal subsidiary American Airlines, ultimately becoming the company's CFO in 2002. He held a variety of financial and operations positions at American, including leading the company’s Europe, Middle East, and Africa operations while based in London.  He began his professional career as a certified public accountant and management consultant with Deloitte, Haskins & Sells.\r\n \r\nJeff has been a board member of Hexcel Corporation since 2003, where he chairs the Audit Committee and is the lead director.  He joined the board of Aon plc in 2018.  He is also a board member of the Lincoln Center for the Performing Arts.\r\n \r\nHe holds an undergraduate degree in Economics from Stanford University and received his Masters of Business Administration from Harvard University in 1990.\r\n \r\nHe and his wife live in New York and have three children.\r\n\r\n",
            "title": "CFO",
            "pic": "/upload/event_68171/inv/3209001/campbell.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "profile": "",
    "logo": "/upload/event_68171/inv/3209001/AXP.png"
},
```

Comment: Your question is confusing and lacks context, also no example of your json structure was included, can you add that?  Also you shouldn't be doing global attribute selectors like that, you should have some kind of child context, like a class wrapper around everything, you can run into conflicts if something else uses that attribute one day.

Can you also add some scope, like what are you trying to accomplish, whats the end goal?  I can see about 1000 ways to do this differently, and optionally better ways.

Comment: @RyanMann I have made some of those edits to clarify the problem.

Comment: You should use a library like vue js, knockout, react, angular, etc where it can handle mapping html to javascript objects for you.  It's a lot more work to do it in vanilla javascript.  At the least, Jquery so you can use jqueries Array searching, $.grep, to search your array for page="syf" and return the match.

Optionally you can use vanilla js's array.filter where you would only return objects where page = the value of the data ticket attribute.  I might write a longer answer when I have more time.